# dc.js reset does not affect mouseZoomable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am using a barchart in dc.js with the x-axis being a timeline of dates and mousezoom works great to zero in from a high level view of 5 years to a smaller subset down to as much as single day ranges. (i.e. Jan 4-Jan 8 2015).

But the problem I am facing is that when I call `reset` or `resetAll` the mouseZoom does not reset. Is there any possible workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `filterAll` as there is no `reset` method.

I don't know your application but can you add

```
chart.focus(null)
```

to your reset click handler, to reset the focus? This is equivalent to what the Range Chart does when the filter is reset.

[coordinateGridMixin.focus documentation](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#coordinategridmixinfocus)